# What's the equivalent of PolyDraw function in GDI+?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+, gdi

I can use [PolyDraw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polydraw) function to draw a continuous custom line segment. But what is the equivalent to that function if I'm using GDI+?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest is GraphicsPath, which stores a group of (possibly) disjoint paths which can be passed to Graphics::DrawPath to be drawn in one call.

See [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-paths-about).

Graphics::FillPath will fill any closed paths you have.

Comment: Thanks. I need to try it before I mark it. But before I do, do you know if that function maintains correct line-joins and start/end-cap settings for that custom line segment?

Comment: I am not certain, but given that GDI+ is mostly stateful I would expect it to.

Comment: Upon further reading, it turns out line caps are an attribute of Pen object which is passed to individual DrawPath calls. You maintain your own state.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to test it too. What I meant is that the first point in this custom line segment should adhere to start-cap setting, then each consecutive segment to line-joins, and lastly the last one to end-cap. That's what `PolyDraw` does (it's supposedly implemented on the graphics driver level.) That is why I am not just breaking it up into my own for-loop which calls those separate functions on its own.